# .htaccess redirect with multiple query string match

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help

my scenario is I want to redirect users (using sample URL)

FORM
www.example.com/affiliate.php?_m=12&fl=345

TO
www.example.com/affiliate.php

I used below rule but it's not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^_m=([0-9]*)&fl=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^affiliate.php$ http://www.example.com/affiliate.php [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Note: I am also using

```
Redirect 301 /affiliate/ http://example.com/affiliate.php
```

to redirect www.example.com/affiliate TO http://example.com/affiliate.php 
which works fine

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: I am also using
Redirect 301 /affiliate/ http://example.com/affiliate.php
```

This is wrong. You can not use `Redirect` with `RewriteRule` . These are 2 diffrent apache modules. `Redirect` directive is part of `alias` module while `RewriteRule` is part of `mod-rewrite` .You can not use them together to handle a similar request as both directives have different runtime behaviour.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^_m=([0-9]*)&fl=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^affiliate.php$ http://www.example.com/affiliate.php? [R=301,L,QSD]
#redirect /affiliate to /affiliate.php
RewriteRule ^affiliate/?$ /affiliate.php [L]
```